# Bypass third-party API file extension block on HTTP requests

Tags: c#, .net, http

I'm trying to do an http post from my .net core service but gets blocked by API (er. 500). But when i do the same request using python works (200).

Others petitions made to the same API doesn't give problems, but this post seems to have some kind of extra validation.

C# code (returns 500):

```
private async Task tests(X509Certificate2 certificate)
        {
            WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
            handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
            handler.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("...");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AddDefaultAccepts();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", "....");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AddDefaultUserAgent();

                MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

                form.Add(new StringContent("..."), "...");
                .
                .
                .
                form.Add(new StringContent("..."), "...");

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync($"....", form);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    
                }        
            }
        }
```

I also tried "FormUrlEncodedContent" with the same results.

Python code (working):

```
import requests_pkcs12

url = '...'
pkcs12_filename = '...'
pkcs12_password = '...'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 'Accept': '...', 'Cookie': '...'}

payload = {'...':'...', '....': '...'}

response = requests_pkcs12.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, verify=False, pkcs12_filename=pkcs12_filename,pkcs12_password=pkcs12_password)
```

The headers and data are the exact same. I think that the API blocks http requests that originates from .exe files. Is there a way to bypass this? Using python is not an option.

Comment: Your python script is also run by an exe-file, and the server have no way to check what process created the request, it only sees the IP/Port, and request data. You might want to use some packet inspecting tool like wireshark to compare the requests, or something like postman that can generate http requests.